# Disjunctive Normal Form Formula

Tags: f#, set, formula, declaration

Im about to use a set-based representation of formulas in disjunctive normal form. And I've found out that since conjunction is commutative, associative and (a ∧ a) is equivalent to a it is convenient to
represent a basic conjunct *bc* by its set of literals **litOf**(*bc*).

Im thinking about representing a disjunctive normal form formula *a*:

bc1 v . . . v bcn

by the set:

```
dnfToSet(a) = {litOf(bc1), . . . , litOf(bcn)}
```

that we will call the dns set of a.

How should i write F# declarations for the functions **litOf** and **dnfToSet** ?

Comment: If my answer completely misses the point, perhaps you could add to your question some example of what litOf and dnfToSet produce as outputs, given some example inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but here is what I came up with:

```
let litOf = Set.ofSeq
let dnfToSet a =
    let isNotSuperset bci = a |> Set.forall(fun bcj -> (bci = bcj) || not(Set.isSuperset bci bcj))
    a |> Set.filter isNotSuperset
```

The following illustrates:

```
type bc = A | B | C | D

let bc1 = litOf [A; B; C]
let bc2 = litOf [B; C; B]
let bc3 = litOf [C; B; A]
let bc4 = litOf [D]
let a = litOf [ bc1; bc2; bc3; bc4 ]
let dnf = dnfToSet a
```

Putting it all into FSI yields:

```
type bc =
  | A
  | B
  | C
  | D
val bc1 : Set<bc> = set [A; B; C]
val bc2 : Set<bc> = set [B; C]
val bc3 : Set<bc> = set [A; B; C]
val bc4 : Set<bc> = set [D]
val a : Set<Set<bc>> = set [set [A; B; C]; set [B; C]; set [D]]
val dnf : Set<Set<bc>> = set [set [B; C]; set [D]]

((B ∧ C) V (D))
```

Finally, for the record, here are functions I used to print the formula:

```
let sprintlit lit =
    System.String.Join(" ∧ ", lit |> Seq.map(sprintf "%A") |> Seq.toArray)
    |> sprintf "(%s)"

let sprintdnf set =
    System.String.Join(" V ", set |> Seq.map sprintlit |> Seq.toArray)
    |> sprintf "(%s)"
```